# In calculation of Hamiltonian of real scalar field (Quantum field theory Srednicki)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, field-theory, fourier-transform, hamiltonian, klein-gordon-equation

I'm now reading the Mark Srednicki, *Quantum field theory,* p.27

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm now trying to understand the Third step in the calculation of $H$.
Through the integration  over $k'$ involving the delta functions
$\delta^{3}(k-k')$(resp. $\delta^{3}(k+k')$), I understand that  $k' \to k$ (resp. $k' \to -k$) in the third step.

Q. But why $\omega' \to \omega$  through the integration over $k'$?

Comment: Please don't post images of lots of text and expect people to read it. Also, images are not searchable. Please type up the *relevant* aspects of the background you need for your question using MathJax (essentially the same syntax as TeX).

Comment: O.K. I will. Anyway, now, I make a furthure progress. Perhaps, if we use $\omega'= (\mathbf{k'}^{2}+m^{2})^{1/2}$ then under the $\mathbf{k'} \to \mathbf{k}$ and $\mathbf{k'} \to \mathbf{-k}$ through the integration, we have $\omega' \to \omega$.